# XBee system: loop() is hanging

Tags: arduino, communication, xbee

For my application, I am using two microcontroller systems, each with an XBee. One is the receiver and one is the transmitter.

The transmitter is a Teensy 3.1, it processes encoder information and **continuously** sends it off to the 2nd system.

The receiving end is an Arduino Due where by it receives the data from the serial channel connected to the XBee and then displays in a serial monitor (using the default UART) of the Arduino IDE.

A weird thing is happening and I cannot understand where the issue may lay. Once the continuously data is paused or stopped, the loop() on the receiving end hangs between 0.5 and 1.5 seconds (non consistent). I know this is occurring because the serial.print function is happening in the loop(), and when the data is paused, the serial monitor pauses as well. Below I have included some code that help.

Teensy 3.1 Transmitting

```html
#define ENCODER_OPTIMIZE_INTERRUPTS

#include <Encoder.h>

long EncoderPosition1 = 0;
long EncoderPosition2 = 0;
long EncoderPosition3 = 0;

Encoder Encoder1(10, 9);
Encoder Encoder2(8, 7);
Encoder Encoder3(12, 11);

void loop() {  
 // Read Controller Encoders
  newEncoderPosition1 = Encoder1.read();
  newEncoderPosition2 = Encoder2.read();
  newEncoderPosition3 = Encoder3.read();
  
  if (newEncoderPosition1 != EncoderPosition1 || newEncoderPosition2 != EncoderPosition2 || newEncoderPosition3 != EncoderPosition3) {
     
    // XBEE TX Position
    Serial1.print(',');
    Serial1.print(newEncoderPosition1);
    Serial1.print(',');
    Serial1.print(newEncoderPosition2);
    Serial1.print(',');
    Serial1.print(newEncoderPosition3);
    Serial1.print(',');
    Serial1.flush();
    
    EncoderPosition1 = newEncoderPosition1;
    EncoderPosition2 = newEncoderPosition2;
    EncoderPosition3 = newEncoderPosition3; 
  }
}
```

Arduino Due Receiving

```html
volatile long EncoderPosition1 = 0; 
volatile long EncoderPosition2 = 0;
volatile long EncoderPosition3 = 0; 

void serialEvent3(){
  EncoderPosition1 = Serial3.parseInt();
  EncoderPosition2 = Serial3.parseInt();
  EncoderPosition3 = Serial3.parseInt();
}

void loop()
{  
  Serial.print(EncoderPosition1);
  Serial.print(',');
  Serial.print(EncoderPosition2);
  Serial.print(',');
  Serial.println(EncoderPosition3);
}
```

Thank you all for help, in advanced.